# WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the warning

```
WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
```

I have code with JPA annotations, but I need them only to use with JOOQ.

How to remove this warning?

Adding my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common:packages:autogenerated_dao')
    externalLib group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: jackson_databind_version
    externalLib group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: javax_validation_version
    externalLib group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: hibernate_validator_version
    externalLib group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: javax_el_version
    externalLib group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: glassfish_el_version
    externalLib group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: javax_persistence_version
}
```

Comment: Post content of your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`

Comment: Added build.gradle file. We use JOOQ for databse operation.

Answer (score 3):

Mentioned warning raised because `javax.persistence-api` dependency present in build file, but obviously here is no implementations for it. To get rid from warning, remove `javax.persistence-api` dependency.
Bean Validation provided by `validation-api` and its implementation `hibernate-validator`, so you will be fine.

Comment: I am using JOOQ so I am binding pojo's properties with @Column. So I need the javax.persistence

Comment: @parthivrshah, you're contradict yourself. You're saying that you don't use JPA and now you're saying that you're using `@Column` annotation. If I understand you correctly, you have code with JPA annotations, but you need them only to use with JOOQ. In this case, since JOOQ is not implementing JPA specification this warning is expected and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thanks, @Sergey. You got me right. But is there any way to get rid of that warning?

Comment: Turn off logging :) In fact I don't see any reason to do so. This is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but for my case was problems with org.hibernate and javax-api version compatibility , so do not use hibernate-core 6.0.0.final versión but maximum 'Alpha' versión. As per documentación says:
'6.0 moves from Java Persistence as defined by the Java EE specs to Jakarta Persistence as defined by the Jakarta EE spec. The most immediate impact of this change is that applications would need to be updated to use the Jakarata Persistence classes (jakarta.persistence.) instead of the Java Persistence ones (javax.persistence.).'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by marking the `jakarta-persistence-api` dependency as being `provided` (project is built using maven) on the module that uses the annotations (so it is no longer a transient dependency).

This was not dead simple though, now I started getting compiler warnings in dependent modules:

```
unknown enum constant jakarta.persistence.EnumType.STRING
  reason: class file for jakarta.persistence.EnumType not found
```

To get rid of these, I had to add the the `jakarta-persistence-api` to each module that emitted the warning (again with `provided` scope).

Alternatively you can keep the dependency as transient and manually exclude it in the modules where see the warning.

JOOQ will still work, since it does not require the jpa classes to be present when checking for the annotations.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing same "**WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.**"
I added below artifact in pom.xml and issue resolved.

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

OR 

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```